# Can I apply Array.prototype.sort to a certain Array-like object which has accessor properties?

Tags: javascript

## Context

```
const impl = Symbol()
class MyArrayLike {
    constructor() {
        this[impl] = [2, 1]
        Object.freeze(this)
    }
    get 0() { return this[impl][0] }
    set 0(value) { this[impl][0] = value }
    get 1() { return this[impl][1] }
    set 1(value) { this[impl][1] = value }
    get length() { return 2 }
}

const xs = new MyArrayLike()
Array.prototype.sort.call(xs) // (A)
console.log(xs[0], xs[1])
```

In above code, I expected to show the sorted values `1 2`. However, the results are different between Chrome and Firefox.

- In Firefox, it behaved as expected. Nice.
- In Chrome, it threw a TypeError at `(A)` because the `this` of accessor properties is `undefined`.

The specification is here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort
But that English is difficult to me.

## Question

Is it a bug that Chrome doesn't give `this` in accessor properties in Array.prototype.sort? Or is it an unspecific behavior by design?

Comment: I found that `this` is not `undefined`, but `this[impl]` is `undefined` in the getter `get 0() { return this[impl][0] }`.

Comment: It does sound like a bug indeed, `sort` should call getters/setters as normal. Please report it to the Chrome/V8 team.

Comment: Notice however that "*The sort order is also implementation-defined if  […] any index property of obj whose name is a nonnegative integer less than len is an accessor property […]*". I guess that this is to deal with getters/setters that essentially make the property non-writable, but you should keep in mind that `sort()` is always allowed to chicken out (and do nothing) if there are getters or setters.

Comment: This was reported at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=7682 and turned out to be a spec issue as well: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working on Chrome is due to the way Chrome and other browsers treat `this` during the sort invocation. In other browsers, `this` continues to be the instance. However, in Chrome, `this` refers to the MyArrayLike prototype, which is where the accessor properties (getters and setters) are defined. On the prototype, the `impl` property doesn't exist (it's on the instance), which is why the result is undefined.

One difference with arrays is that they seem to be defining properties for each of the indices on the instance itself, rather than the prototype. You can test this out by invoking Object.getOwnPropertyNames() on an array instance. This will return an array of the indices, and "length". On the other hand, if you try to invoke that function on an instance of your class, it returns an empty array.

If you would like your code to work on Chrome also, one way out can be to define the properties on the instance itself, like in the snippet below:

```js
var impl = Symbol()
class MyArrayLike {
    constructor() {
        this[impl] = [2, 1];
  Object.defineProperty(this, 0, {
   get: function() { return this[impl][0] },
   set: function(value) { this[impl][0] = value }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, 1, {
   get: function() { return this[impl][1] },
   set: function(value) { this[impl][1] = value }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, "length", {
   get: function() { return 2; }
  });
        Object.freeze(this)
    }
    
}

var xs = new MyArrayLike();
Array.prototype.sort.call(xs);
console.log(xs[0], xs[1]);
```

Whether this is a bug or not, is something that might need to be checked from the Chrome team. However, it could also just be a difference in the implementation by Chrome.